# Gravity is an intrinsic property of every atoms?

Tags: gravity, particle-physics

1. If gravity is the force of attraction between masses, does this force is an intrinsic property of every atoms?
2. Is there any possibility of some other particles within atom which is yet to be discovered?
3. Or is it simply a result of cosmic waves which created due to big bang?
4. Does anyone have any information regarding variations in gravitational force?
5. If its not there then is it simply be "something like plasma which entire universe in within its plume and huge masses simply accelerate the attraction"?

Comment: Gravity is a force exerted not only by every atom but by every elementary particle, every mass in any form, and every energy, including potential energy between elementary particles, and it acts on everything - all forms of energy-mass, too. Experiments prove the "equivalence principle" - the fact that mass is subject to equally strong gravity regardless of the form - with the relative precision of $10^{-16}$ in some situations. Einstein's general relativity describes gravity in terms of a curved spacetime. No "plasma" is involved.

Answer (score 2):

Atoms are overrated among laymen, gravity is a property of all matter, regardless of what particle structures it is comprised of -- for example, light, dark matter, government bureaucrats and other exotic forms of matter all exhibit gravity.

That answers your first question -- I have no idea what the others are supposed to mean, what their words mean and how they are connected.